# Numpy проблема с копированием,

Tags: python, numpy

В общем есть код:

```
a = [
    np.array([1,2,3,4]),
    np.array([1,2,3])
]

b = np.array(a)
b += 100

print(a) # [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

Как сделать так что бы оригинальные данные в списке `a` тоже изменились после этой операции `b += 100` ? Т.е. требуемый результат:

```
print(a) # [array([101, 102, 103, 104]), array([101, 102, 103])]
```

Более подробно:
Есть много тензоров разной формы, находящихся в разных местах программы, для простоты пусть лежат в одном списке:

```
a = [
    np.array([1,2,3]),
    np.array([1,2])
]
```

Далее все эти тензоры собираются в один список:

```
c = [i for i in a]
```

Далее эти тензоры суммируются с другими тензорами (той же формы):

```
c = np.array(c)
c += 100
```

В результате оригинальные тензоры которые находятся в разных местах программы, 
 а здесь в виде массивов в `a` должны тоже измениться после операции `c += 100`, проблема в том что происходит копирование здесь `c = np.array(c)`, как добиться нужного результата не прибегая к циклам и т.д. ?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [2]: b = [100+x for x in a]

In [3]: b
Out[3]: [array([101, 102, 103, 104]), array([101, 102, 103])]
```

NOTE: для того чтобы превратить список списков или список NDArray в полноценную Numpy матрицу, все вложенные списки / векторы / матрицы должны быть **одинаковой** размерности.

---

**UPDATE:** ответ от @Andrey натолкнул на мысль:

```
In [19]: a = [
    ...:     np.array([1,2,3,4]),
    ...:     np.array([1,2,3])
    ...: ]

In [20]: a = np.asarray(a)
#               ^^

In [21]: a += 100

In [22]: a
Out[22]: array([array([101, 102, 103, 104]), array([101, 102, 103])], dtype=object)
```

но все равно это похоже на "грязный хак"... Обычно в такой ситуации выравнивают (дополняют нулями) вложенные матрицы таким образом, чтобы можно было получить обычный nD тензор.

Comment: В том то и проблема что нужна векторизация, приходиться выполнять масштабные вычисления с тензорами, и такого рода циклы будут только в минус, очень не хочу к ним прибегать. Нужна векторизованая операция на месте, неужели нельзя обойти это копирование

Comment: данные в `a` же не изменились

Comment: сейчас более подробно опишу вопрос

Comment: я так понял, кроме циклов не как ?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, что то ничего на ум не приходит...

Answer (score 1):

А что если изначально объявить `a` как `np.array`?

```
a = np.array([
    np.array([1,2,3,4]),
    np.array([1,2,3])
])

b = a
b += 100

print(a)
print(b)

# [array([101, 102, 103, 104]) array([101, 102, 103])]
# [array([101, 102, 103, 104]) array([101, 102, 103])]
```